# When i tried to build the contract npx locklift build Getting the below error

Tags: node.js, npm, everscale, ton, venom

When i tried to build the contract

npx locklift build

Getting the below error

[ERROR] path: /home/user/venom/hello-venom/contracts/Sample.tsol, contractFile: Sample. error: /bin/sh: 1: /home/user/.cache/locklift-nodejs/compiler/0_62_0/solc_0_62_0_linux: not found

Anyone faced similar issue?>

I am expected to find a solution of that problem